# Why Integer.toBinaryString returns 32 bits if the argument is negative?

Tags: java, integer, bit-manipulation

I was just messing around the `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` method.

When I pass a positive number say 7, it outputs `111` but when I pass negative 7, it outputs `11111111111111111111111111111001`. I understand that Java uses 2's complement to represent negative numbers, but why 32 bits (I also know that an int is 32 bits long but doesn't fit in the answer)?

Comment: All `int` values are 32-bit, and it removes leading zeros but for negative numbers, it will have a top bit set.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here.  You say you understand 2's complement, yet you don't understand why negative numbers have those leading 1s?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I mean why would you add rest all the bits as 1 instead of just one signed bit?

Comment: @Vwin: Because that's how 2's complement works.

Comment: I am getting your point but you are stating it wrong. 2's complement has nothing to do with adding 1's before. It is because as @peter stated ,the number for example 7 has leading 0's which are inverted to all 1's

Comment: @Vwin you may should check how the 2'S complement works. Short: you take the binary representation of a number, invert *all* bits (int is 32 bit long that means you have to invert all 32 bits) and add 1 to this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I did some digging...

I wrote up a little program probably close to what you did.

```
public class IntTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 7;
        int b = -7;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
    }
}
```

My output:

111

11111111111111111111111111111001

So 111 is the same if it had 29 "0"s in front of it. That is just wasted space and time.

If we follow the instructions for twos compliment from this guy [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXAr35BiqK8) you can see that what we must do is flip the bits ( zeros become ones and ones become zeros ) then we add 1 to the result.

So 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 becomes 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001

The ones can not be thrown out because they are significant in the twos compliment representation. This is why you have 32 bits in the second case.

Hope this helps! -- Code on!!!

Comment: You are right. It was confusing because the leading 0's are not displayed.

Comment: Yeah think of it like 500 being represent like 00500, you can put as many zeros in front of the 5 and it doesn't change the value of it.

Answer (score 2):

It outputs the smallest number it can, stripping leading zeroes.  In the case of a negative number, the first bit of the 32 bits is a sign bit (i.e. -1 is 1, 30 zeros, and another 1).  So, since it has to output the sign bit (it's significant), it outputs all 32 bits.

Here's a cool semi-relevant example of using the sign bit and the unsigned shift operator :).  If you do:

```
int x = {positive_value};
int y = {other_positive_value};
int avg = (x + y) >>> 1;
```

The x and y integers can both use the first 31 bits since the 32nd bit is the sign.  This way, if they overflow, they overflow into the sign bit and make the value negative.  The >>> is an unsigned shift operator which shifts the value back one bit to the right which is effectively a divide by two and floor operation, which gives a proper average.

If you, on the other hand, had done:

```
int x = {value};
int y = {other_value};
int avg = (x + y) / 2;
```

And you had gotten an overflow, you would end up with the wrong result as you'd be dividing a negative value by 2.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java ints are signed 32-bit. If you use a negative number the first bit must be 1.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // 31 bits
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)); // 31 bits
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)); // 32 bits
System.out.println(Integer.SIZE);
```

Output is

```
0
1111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111110
10000000000000000000000000000000
32
```

Note that `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (and it has an extra bit).

Comment: But my question was why so many 1's. I got my answer it is because the positive number itself has leading 0 which when inverted has all 1's. The cionfusion arises because Java does not diplay the leading 0's for a positive number.